# Sequential fade in efect with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, frontend

I was trying to make my own intro for my landing page. Is there something I'm missing or what? My page doesn't show anything but a black screen.

```js
$(function() {
  var welcomeSection = $('.welcome-section'),
    enterButton = welcomeSection.find('.enter-button');

  setTimeOut(function() {
    welcomeSection.removeClass('content-hidden');
  }, 800);

  enterButton.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    welcomeSection.addClass('content-hidden').fadeOut();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome-section content-hidden">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <ul class="fly-in-text">
      <li>H</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>L</li>
      <li>L</li>
      <li>O</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="enter-button">ENTER</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you got any error on console?

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet. You can see the issue now: `setTimeOut` needs to be `setTimeout`. Note that JS is case-sensitive. Also note that you can easily check the console to debug JS when it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: hi thanks yeah i'm not seeing that case-sensitive thing this time .t

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Consider changing the title with something relevant like: "Sequential fade in efect with jQuery not working".

Comment: yours answer really helped me really appreciate it and thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

There is no `setTimeOut` function in JavaScript. Try `setTimeout` instead. Remember Java Script is **case sensitive**.

```js
$(function() {
  var welcomeSection = $('.welcome-section'),
    enterButton = welcomeSection.find('.enter-button'),
    greating = $('.content-wrap');

  enterButton.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    greating.fadeIn();
  })
});
```

```css
.welcome-section {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.fly-in-text {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fly-in-text li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #c00;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome-section">
  <a href="#" class="enter-button">ENTER</a>
  <div class="content-wrap hidden">
    <ul class="fly-in-text">
      <li>H</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>L</li>
      <li>L</li>
      <li>O</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the letters one by one too:

```js
var showLetters = function () {
  var letter = $('.fly-in-text').find('li');

  letter.each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(200*i).fadeIn("show");
  });
}

$('.enter-button').on('click', showLetters);
```

```css
.welcome-section {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fly-in-text {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fly-in-text li {
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #c00;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome-section">
  <a href="#" class="enter-button">ENTER</a>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <ul class="fly-in-text">
      <li>H</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>L</li>
      <li>L</li>
      <li>O</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```